# How to compare between two dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary where I want to compare and print out the difference between the dicts.

```
old_state = {
    'https://github.com/search?q=i+love+python': {'title': 'i love python', 'repo_count': '517'},
    'https://github.com/search?q=python+3': {'title': 'python 3', 'repo_count': '101K'},
    'https://github.com/search?q=world': {'title': 'world', 'repo_count': '1M'},
    'https://github.com/search?q=hello+world': {'title': 'hello world', 'repo_count': '1M'}
}

new_state = {
    'https://github.com/search?q=python+3': {'title': 'python 3', 'repo_count': '102K'},
    'https://github.com/search?q=world': {'title': 'world', 'repo_count': '1M'},
    'https://github.com/search?q=hello+world': {'title': 'hello world', 'repo_count': '1M'},
    'https://github.com/search?q=i+love+python': {'title': 'i love python', 'repo_count': '517'}
}
```

This is the dict that I have done and so far I managed to solve my issue without using the key and value but to just have a value something like this:

```
old_state = {'title': 'i love python', 'repo_count': '517'}
new_state = {'title': 'python 3', 'repo_count': '102K'}

if old_state['title'] != new_state['title']:
   print('new change in title')
if old_state['repo_count'] != new_state['repo_count']:
   print('new change in repo count')
```

The output is the one that I wish to have when it comes to a bigger dictionary with nested dicts of dict(key-value). However my knowledge is not that great yet to know how to do it with bigger dictionaries when it comes to having key-value. My question is, is it possible to do it with the dictionary that I have stated in the beginning and if yes, how am I able to have an output of what I have shown before?

Comment: using `old_state['title']` you're actually using `key` and `value`. Key is `'title'` and the value is the `old_state` content. to achive your check you could use `for` cycle

Comment: @NicoCaldo Oh that is true, the only diference now is that I have a nested dict of dicts? Meaning that I have `{URL: dict}`

Comment: I think your question is not clear. First you have a dictionary with url in your first code block, then you mentioned another dictionary in the second code block. Then you mentioned ***The output is the one that I wish to have when it comes to a bigger dictionary with nested dicts of dict(key-value)***. If you rephrase your question it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the common keys. Then I compared them according to the value value and printed the ones with different values. That's the main logic. You can manipulate the code however you want.

```
old_keys = old_state.keys()
new_keys = new_state.keys()

# Print non-common key values
dif1 = [x for x in new_keys if x not in set(old_keys)]
dif2 = [x for x in old_keys if x not in set(new_keys)]
print(f"non-common key values {dif1} and {dif2}")

# print common key but different values 
intersect_keys = set(old_keys).intersection(set(new_keys))

for i in intersect_keys:
    if old_state[i] !=  new_state[i]:
        print(f"{i} for old_state = {old_state[i]} and {i} for new_state={new_state[i]}")
        
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: I saw a small flaw where I believe you wanted to write `new_keys = old_state.keys()` -> new_state.keys()

Comment: yes. i fix that

Comment: I tried to do some changes to see how it reacts whenever there is a new url in new_state - and it seems liek it does not find if a new URL gets added to the dict

Comment: Are you sure? I didn't see any problems when I tested it. Look carefully at the output.

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/fuvayonese.py -> here we should detect the "https://github.com/search?q=hello+world"

Comment: In the code I throw, it only finds the common keys and checks if the values ​​are different. You also want it to find non-partners?

Comment: That would be a good cover aswell I would say, if possible ofc

Answer (score 2):

I would proceed by creating a Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.merge(
    pd.DataFrame(old_state).T,
    pd.DataFrame(new_state).T,
    left_index=True, right_index=True,
    suffixes=["_old", "_new"] 
)
```

[image]

now you can check the changes with:

```
if (df.title_old!=df.title_new).any():
    print('new change in title')
if (df.repo_count_old!=df.repo_count_new).any():
    print('new change in repo count')
```

Thanks to the Dataframe you can also print the information of the change. For example, in your case:

```
df.loc[df.repo_count_old!=df.repo_count_new, ["repo_count_old", "repo_count_new"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate it! I think this might be abit overcomplicated for what I wish to do but this is very knowledgeable for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can cycle using the `keys()` function

```
for x in new_state.keys():
  if old_state[x]['title'] != new_state[x]['title']:
    print('new change in title')
  if old_state[x]['repo_count'] != new_state[x]['repo_count']:
    print('new change in repo count')
```

Basically `keys` retrieve all the keys of your dictionary and you can use them to cycle over the nested dictionary

Instead of using `new_state.keys()` you can use `old_state.keys()` or the dictionary with the smaller number of keys (if you took the bigger one it trows error because it can't find some keys)

Because the code above trows error if keys are different you can create a new key set with the intersection of the keys that are in common with both dictionary using `set(old_state.keys()).intersection(new_state.keys())`

So the cycle will be

```
for x in set(old_state.keys()).intersection(new_state.keys())
```

Comment: I dont think will work as the order of the dictionary is not the same.

Comment: According to your question "My question is, is it possible to do it with the dictionary that I have stated in the beginning and if yes, how am I able to have an output of what I have shown before?" This is a correct answer. If it doesn't suite for your specific case, you should update the question with specific info

Comment: Actually I misunderstood, im sorry. the x would work as its the URL. I believe this actually does the work for me

Comment: `x` tooks each value of the list created by `new_state.keys()`. So it will be `https://github.com/search?q=i+love+python` `https://github.com/search?q=python+3` and so on

Comment: Exactly so we are checking directly the x into the `old_state or new_state` - Super clever!

Comment: Im not sure if I am following the the last part where you added `set(old_state.keys()).intersection(new_state.keys())` - Cant you jsut do if x not in old_state ?

Comment: yes, no metter the order, intersection find the keys that are on both dictionary

Comment: So do you mean instead of using `for x in new_state.keys():` we should use `for x in set(old_state.keys()).intersection(new_state.keys())` instead?

Comment: Because I tried now to do https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/ujoriceqod.rb` and and that printed out the url's which I believe shouldn't happen as well as it didn't printed out a new URL I added in the dict.

Comment: you missed `new_state.keys()` on the `intersection` function. Please check the code carefully

Comment: Sorry, just added that and tested. Same result.

Comment: please add all the info we need and be clear with your question as you continue to add and edit your inputs

Answer (score 1):

I'd iterate over all keys and if the change is in a dict, do it recursively, so you can see both the URL and the changed keys:

```
def diff(old, new):
    for key in new.keys():
        try:
            if old[key] != new[key]:
                print(f'New change in {key}')
                if type(new[key]) == dict:
                    diff(old[key], new[key])
        except KeyError:
            print(f'New key added: {key}')
            
    for key in old.keys():
        try:
            new[key]
        except KeyError:
            print(f'Key removed: {key}')

diff(old_state, new_state)
```

The try and except blocks handle the case if some keys are added or removed.

So it has an output like this:

```
New key added: https://github.com/search?q=new
New change in https://github.com/search?q=python+3
New change in repo_count
Key removed: https://github.com/search?q=old
```